# Comparing decimals in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to filter my database by a column that stores sales value as decimals

```cs
public class Order
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
    public decimal SalesValue { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Here is the LINQ I have tried

```
orders = orders.Where(x => x.SalesValue >= 10000.00M);
```

However this gives the error:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet .Where(o
>   => o.SalesValue >= 10000.00)' could not be translated.

and this which does not filter at all

```
Decimal value = new Decimal(10000);
Where(x => Decimal.Compare(x.SalesValue, value) >= 0);
```

How can I filter a decimal column?

Comment: EF Core version? Because `Where(x => x.SalesValue >= 10000.00M)` perfectly translates in EFC3.1.5. Also, are we sure you didn't `Ignore` the column?

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm using 3.1.4, Don't think I've ignored it, not sure how to ignore a column in the first place

Comment: You ignore it with `[NotMapped]` attribute or `modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().Ignore(x => x.SalesValue)`. Anyway, actually both your examples translate on my side.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or SQLite I'm using SQLite and think that might have something to do with it

Comment: I'm with SqlServer

Comment: did you solve the problem? With latest efcore i'm still facing the issue

Comment: @nemenos Yes, dont think decimals are supported in SQLite, I transferred to SQL Server and everything worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you further go down to the error you should be having Microsoft Link to tell the exact reason for the error! In my case when I tried your code I got the below `exception`.

> 'The LINQ expression 'Where(
>       source: DbSet, 
>       predicate: (v) => v.SalesValue >= 10000.00)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
>   or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
>   either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
>   ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
>   more information.'

If we go to the link and explore [`Unsupported client evaluation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#unsupported-client-evaluation) for the issue you are facing!

One approach would be too use - [`Explicit client evaluation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#explicit-client-evaluation) some thing like below if you have small amount of data:

```
var orders = _context.Values.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.SalesValue >= 10000.00M).ToList();
```

There are some other considerations you may have to take depending upon your data and business model which you can further get the information from above link!

> As a general rule, Entity Framework Core attempts to evaluate a query
>   on the server as much as possible. EF Core converts parts of the query
>   into parameters, which it can evaluate on the client side. The rest of
>   the query (along with the generated parameters) is given to the
>   database provider to determine the equivalent database query to
>   evaluate on the server.

Answer (score 0):

While developing a project on [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/), due to a similar [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) query, I got the error shown below by [dotnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/):

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 
'DbSet<Product>.Where(p => p.Price >= __price_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the
query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting 
a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

I discovered that this problem is solved using the cast operator. Since the base data type `decimal` is *floating point* and the use of the `double` cast operator is allowed in the current context, I developed the following solution:

```cs
///<summary>Entity Class</summary>
public class Product
{
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
    
  [MaxLength(100)]
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

///<summary>In a scenario where Entity Framework Core is used by the ApplicationLayer class in the application layer, call the PrintProductsByMinimumPrice() method from the Main() method. </summary>
public class ApplicationLayer
{
  ///<summary>Using the "double" cast operator on the line where the "Where" LINQ query is used will work in solving this problem. </summary>
  public static void PrintProductsByMinimumPrice(decimal price)
  {
    using(var context = ProductContext())
    {
      var products = context.Products
                            .Where(product => ((double)product.Price) => (double)price)
                            .Select(product => new { product.ID, product.Name })
                            .ToList();

      foreach(var product in products)
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"ID: {product.ID}\tName: {product.Name}");
      }
    }
  }
}
```